# How to take a picture to show in a `ImageView` and save the picture?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview

I need to take a **picture** with the `camera`, save the **picture**, show in `ImageView` and when I click the `Imageview` show in **fullscreen** mode .

In the future will need to send the **picture** to the `internet`.

This is what I've done :

```
public void captureImage(View v) {
    Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.formRegister_picture);
    imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode){
        case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST:
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                imgView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke camera Activity by adding these lines in your code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);              
private static int RESULT_IMAGE_CLICK = 1;

                cameraImageUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(1);

                // set the image file name
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cameraImageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_IMAGE_CLICK);
```

Now create file `Uri` because in some android phones you will get `null` data in `return`

so here is the method to get the image `URI` :

```
 /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
        private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {

            return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
        }

        /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
        private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

            // Check that the SDCard is mounted
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

            // Create the storage directory(MyCameraVideo) if it does not exist
            if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {

                if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {

                    Log.e("Item Attachment",
                            "Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.");

                    return null;
                }
            }
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        String timeStamp = getTimeStamp();

        File mediaFile;

        if (type == 1) {

            // For unique video file name appending current timeStamp with file
            // name
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +abc+ ".jpg");

        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

For retrieving clicked image :

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == RESULT_IMAGE_CLICK) {


    // Here you have the ImagePath which you can set to you image view
                    Log.e("Image Name", cameraImageUri.getPath());

         Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cameraImageUri.getPath()); 

            yourImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);



// For further image Upload i suppose your method for image upload is UploadImage
File imageFile = new File(cameraImageUri.getPath());
                uploadImage(imageFile);

                        }




            }
        }
```

Comment: `getExternalStorageDirectory` is now deprecated and Context should be used here

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no proper solution for this, I will put here what I have put together that is working and correct.

```
ImageButton takepic = (ImageButton) returnView.findViewById(R.id.takepic);

    takepic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) { Intent intent = new Intent();
                            addPhoto();
                        }

                    });
```

Android Manifest :

```
   <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

Android Manifest again at the top :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

External res/xml/file_paths.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="my_images" />
</paths>
```

CreateImageFile Function

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
     storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

    return image;
}
```

AddPhoto Function

```
private void addPhoto() {
    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.MEDIA_IGNORE_FILENAME, ".nomedia");

        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "profileimg");

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File

    }
    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
    if (photoFile != null) {
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                photoFile);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 100);}
}
```

On activity callback

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        try {

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            ImageButton takepic = (ImageButton) returnView.findViewById(R.id.takepic);
            if (extras!=null){
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+mCurrentPhotoPath);


                takepic.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }


            String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

            // Split at colon, use second item in the array
            String idx = wholeID.split(":")[1];

            String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            // where id is equal to
            String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

            Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().
                    query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            column, sel, new String[]{idx}, null);

            String filePath = "";

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            }

            cursor.close();


            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            takepic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Uploading In Progress",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to save image to file explorer:

```
   public void captureImage(View v) {
    Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.png");
        camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
            f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("image.png")) {
                    f = temp;
                    imagePath= f.getAbsolutePath();
                    Bitmap thumbnail= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(), options);
imgView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}
```

You can fetch image from path "imagePath" whenever you have to display it.