# capturing an image through camera and saving it into the gallery

Tags: android, image-gallery, onactivityresult

I have made a button which on clicks opens a camera and captures the image. But then it doesnot show on the imageview i made and doesnot even save in the gallery. I think i have written the right code but the flow seems to written in wrong way.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE=1;

ImageView img;
String mCurrentPhotoPath;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && requestCode==RESULT_OK )
    {
        Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitMap=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageBitmap(imageBitMap);

    }
}


private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}


}
```

Comment: //try update media cursors forcefully if it is not available until it updated
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(...path of your image file))));

Comment: Duplicate of of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445156/how-to-take-a-picture-to-show-in-a-imageview-and-save-the-picture May be this will help you!

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445156/how-to-take-a-picture-to-show-in-a-imageview-and-save-the-picture

Comment: if(requestCode==REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && requestCode==RESULT_OK ) this line change it to resultCode==RESULT_OK

Answer (score 0):

In some context, we need to update media cursours forcefully to visible in mobile gallery. Therefore try below code segment to update your media forcefully.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,Uri.fromFile(new File(...path of your image file))));
```

Comment: Where to put this statement

Comment: after complete your image saving part.

Comment: didnt work.. Put this statement at the of the createImageFile method

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your code, `createImageFile()` is not called any where. I think that inside your `dispatchTakePictureIntent` you should insert some additional code and make it this way:

```java
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {


            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.provider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }

    }
}
```

And you should create, inside your xml folder under resources folder, a file named 'file_paths.xml' where you can write the code below if not yet done:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Remember also to declare the provider in the Manifest file like this:

```xml
 <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Remember to replace **YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME** by your real package name.  Then inside your `onActivityResult` method, get the bitmap this way:

```java
 File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media
                        .getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));
```

img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Try step by step, refine if possible and give feedback. Ask for clarifications in comments but try first please.